# Pagination with json in WordPress

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, pagination

I'm trying to get some json output from a paginated url. It's works without the pagination, but does not work when I add the end pieces.

What could possibly be wrong with this?

```
if ($last_segment == 'getEvents') {
    $vars = explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    // /events/api/getEvents/page/1/pagesize/10
    //print_r($vars); die;
    if (isset($vars[7])) {
        $posts_per_page = $vars[7];
        $offset = ($vars[5] - 1) * $posts_per_page;
    } else {
        $posts_per_page = -1;
        $offset = 0;
    }
    getEvents($posts_per_page, $offset, isset($vars[9]) ? $vars[9] : NULL );
}
```

Edit:

```
print_r($vars); die;
```

yields:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => events [2] => api [3] => getEvents )
```

using:
`/api/getEvents` (without pagination)

Comment: wouldn't it be $vars[6] instead of vars7? sounds like a classic off by 1 error.

Comment: Tried this: didn't work. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a classic off by one error, php arrays start at 0, so unless explode("/") is giving you an empty first argument from the request_URI.

Could you dump the value of REQUEST_URI and $VARS to your question to assist debugging?

anyway, my attempt:

```
if ($last_segment == 'getEvents') {
    $vars = explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    // /events/api/getEvents/page/1/pagesize/10
    //print_r($vars); die;
    if (isset($vars[6])) {
        $posts_per_page = $vars[6];
        $offset = ($vars[4] - 1) * $posts_per_page;
    } else {
        $posts_per_page = -1;
        $offset = 0;
    }
    getEvents($posts_per_page, $offset, isset($vars[9]) ? $vars[9] : NULL );
}
```